# Ansible winrm with virtualenv

Tags: python, jenkins, ansible, winrm

I'm trying to work with ansible, winrm, virtualenv and Jenkins...
Currently, I have installed Ansible with Tom via epel-release.

Jenkins has only basic configuration for now.

I have then created a virtualenv inside Jenkins home named `$HOME/ansible-winrm`. Then inside it, I have installed winrm via pip.

What I'm trying to do is :
- create a simple job on Jenkins with only a shell script calling `ansible-playbook`. And it should access to the winrm library installed inside my local virtualenv.
- It should be as transparent as possible.

P.S. It seems that python binary is hard codded inside `ansible-playbook` script.

What are your best practices to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is installing `winrm` with pip in user workspace (option `--user`)

Ex: `pip install --user pywinrm`